# analphabetic strings decidable by DFA?

Tags: dfa

Is the language of panalphabetic strings decidable by DFA? If so, how can I prove it?

A string {a,…,z}* is said to be panalphabetic if it contains at least one occurrence of each letter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is decidable by a DFA, albeit one that needs 2<sup>26</sup> (that is, 67108864) states.

The easiest way to prove this is probably by the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem). To use that, you'll need to divide all strings into equivalence classes based on what can be added to the string to make it part of the language. (see the wikipedia article)

To do that, define a function *f* over strings in {a,...,z}* that is the set of all letters in the string. Obviously, for any two strings *x* and *y*, *f(xy)* is *f(x)* ⋃ *f(y)*. (That is, the union of *f(x)* and *f(y)*)

The language of panalphabetic strings is then all strings *s* such that *f(s)* is the set of all letters. That is, whether a string is panalphabetic can be determined just by what the value of *f* applied to that string is.

Now consider two strings *x* and *y* such that *f(x)* = *f(y)*. Then, for any third string *z*, *f(xz)* = *f(x)* ⋃ *f(z)* = *f(y)* ⋃ *f(z)* = *f(yz)*. Therefore, *xz* is panalphabetic if and only if *yz* is panalphabetic. Therefore, *x* and *y* are equivalent.

Therefore, there can only be as many different equivalence classes as there are possible values of *f*. Since *f(s)* is a subset of {a, b, ..., z}, there are only 2<sup>26</sup> possible values of *f(s)*. This is finite, so the language of panalphabetic strings is recognizable by a DFA.

(To show that 2<sup>26</sup> is the smallest number of DFA states, you also need to show that if *f(x)* != *f(y)*, then *x* and *y* are **not** equivalent, which therefore means that there are exactly as many equivalence classes as there are possible values for *f(s)*. That's fairly straightforward, but I'll let you complete that bit)